WiFi adapter not found error in Ubuntu 24.04
I installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.
I have a RTL8723BE WiFi adapter.
After installation, I'm not able to find the WiFi adapter nor the WiFi symbol.
Also the WiFi adapter is not listed in the lspci output.
Surprisingly enough, Bluetooth works perfectly fine. However, if I try to disable Bluetooth, Airplane mode gets turned on and if I try to disable Airplane Mode, Bluetooth gets turned on.
I remember reading somewhere that Bluetooth and wifi chip is same for RTL8723BE. Not exactly sure of the specifics. Maybe this can help ?
Edit - Adding the details as asked by @Jeremy31
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/XWKgF75gxY/
########## wireless info START ##########

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

##### kernel ############################

Linux 6.8.0-44-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Aug 13 13:35:26 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [103c:81f0]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. Integrated Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:b008 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05c8:038f Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP TrueVision HD
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 2717:ff80 Xiaomi Inc. Mi/Redmi series (RNDIS)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode

##### lsmod #############################

rtl8723be             176128  0
btcoexist             290816  1 rtl8723be
rtl8723_common         24576  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci                40960  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi               139264  4 rtl_pci,rtl8723be,btcoexist,rtl8723_common
mac80211             1720320  3 rtl_pci,rtl8723be,rtlwifi
cfg80211             1323008  2 rtlwifi,mac80211
libarc4                12288  1 mac80211
hp_wmi                 28672  0
sparse_keymap          12288  1 hp_wmi
platform_profile       12288  1 hp_wmi
wmi_bmof               12288  0
wmi                    28672  3 hp_wmi,video,wmi_bmof

##### dkms #############################

./wireless-info: line 206: dkms: command not found

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp7s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp7s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
4: enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.42.76/24 brd 192.168.42.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
       valid_lft 2375sec preferred_lft 2375sec
    inet6 fe80::2a81:c116:3518:a7cb/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp7s0    no wireless extensions.

enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.42.129 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF2]> proto dhcp src 192.168.42.76 metric 100 
192.168.42.0/24 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF2]> proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.76 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root        1010       1  0 15:34 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Xiaomi Inc.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Mi/Redmi series (RNDIS)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rndis_host
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.8.0-44-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               RNDIS device
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/net/enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 2
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       bcc4434a-e8db-3192-b7bb-7a7cd4f7df4b
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.42.76/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.42.129
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.42.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.42.129, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.42.255
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_client_identifier = 01:<MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]>
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 3600
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        expiry = 1726054103
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        ip_address = 192.168.42.76
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        next_server = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       routers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::2a81:c116:3518:a7cb/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/6
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   bcc4434a-e8db-3192-b7bb-7a7cd4f7df4b | Wired connection 2

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp7s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.8.0-44-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp7s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:07:00.0/net/enp7s0
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:07:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=false

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

grep: /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml: Permission denied
grep: /lib/netplan/00-network-manager-all.yaml: Permission denied

##### iw reg get ########################

'iw' is not installed (package "iw").

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp7s0    no frequency information.

enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp7s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8723be]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.8.0-44-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.ko.zst
description:    Realtek 8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
depends:        rtl8723-common,rtlwifi,mac80211,rtl_pci,btcoexist
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtl8723be
vermagic:       6.8.0-44-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0)
parm:           aspm:Set to 1 to enable ASPM (default 1)
parm:           debug_level:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
parm:           debug_mask:Set debug mask (default 0) (ullong)
parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
parm:           ant_sel:Set to 1 or 2 to force antenna number (default 0)

[rtl8723_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.8.0-44-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723com/rtl8723-common.ko.zst
description:    Realtek RTL8723AE/RTL8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless common routines
license:        GPL
depends:        rtlwifi
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtl8723_common
vermagic:       6.8.0-44-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 

[rtl_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.8.0-44-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko.zst
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
depends:        rtlwifi,mac80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtl_pci
vermagic:       6.8.0-44-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.8.0-44-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko.zst
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtlwifi
vermagic:       6.8.0-44-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.8.0-44-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko.zst
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
depends:        cfg80211,libarc4
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       6.8.0-44-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.8.0-44-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko.zst
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       6.8.0-44-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rtl8723be]
ant_sel: 1
aspm: 1
debug_level: 0
debug_mask: 0
disable_watchdog: N
fwlps: Y
ips: Y
msi: N
swenc: N
swlps: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[ 1490.443999] rndis_host 2-1:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: renamed from usb0


See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and provide the results of the script

@Jeremy31
Here's the link. Thanks in advance.
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/XWKgF75gxY/

Might need to reset BIOS to defaults as it isn't detecting wifi at all

Did that...still the same @Jeremy31

Any wifi settings in BIOS?  Otherwise you may have to remove and reinstall the wifi card itself

No specific wifi settings in BIOS. Before it used to run Linux Mint and wifi used to work perfectly fine. Donno what happened, suddenly wifi started disconnecting and stuff. Since I had only ubuntu boot drive with me, installed this.

For now, one thing is for certain. The wifi card works perfectly fine.
Fed up with the hardware compatibility issues, I installed Windows back.
After installing the driver, the wifi is back up and working.
Just have to wait till Ubuntu works on supporting RTL8723BE wifi card.
Or someone from the community finds a fix.
Thanks for the help.
